# iPhone Product Name

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I have an App already live on the App Store and I am now releasing an update for it. But I added the In-App feature to the app and realized my app name in iTunes Connect and the product name in XCode were different and the in-app didn't work. So I changed the product name in XCode to match iTunes Connect and the in-app purchase works. My question is if the product name change is going to break the update?

The reason I ask this is because when I test the app on devices with the original version, xcode cannot launch the app and results in an error. So I have to manually delete the original version from the test devices and then let xcode install it and then it debugs. Will the end users have to do the same too when I release the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bundle Identifier (com.yourcompany.Appname) is what makes the application unique on the device. If you rename the application but leave the Bundle Identifier identical then the app will simply be replaced and show up with the new name.

Comment: Thanks St3fan,
I didn't change the bundle name.